# How is remainder calculated with modulo when solving fractions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As you can see, dividing 3/7 yields a fraction. But when I do 3%7 it yields 3. How could this be? I suppose I expected an output value of 4 (because it would take 4 to complete 7) or 0, (because there is no remainder at all if you use integer division such as 3//7).

```
>>> 3/7
0.42857142857142855
>>> 3%7
3
>>>
```

Just trying to understand the depths of Python. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Re-reading your question, it occurred to me you got your terms mixed up and that may have been the underlying confusion that none of us properly answered.

> But when I do 3%7 it yields 3. How could this be? I suppose I expected an output value of 4 (because it would take 4 to complete 7)

So first that issue was masked when you said 4. Since 4 is greater than 3, 3 can be subtracted a *second* time, leaving 1. So `1` is the output of `7 % 3`.

**But** you asked about `3 % 7`, even though you then proceeded to explain `7 % 3`. `3 % 7` is less than 1 (because 7 > 3). So *that* is why the modulus is still 3. Integer division gives you 0, so 3 is left.

Take the first term (3) divided by the second term (7) using integer division (resulting in 0). Subtract that number from the first term (3) and you get 3. So: `3 % 7 = 3`

Answer (score 5):

Remember long division? Before you learned about fractions, `50 divided by 7` would be `7, remainder 1`.  The `remainder` is the modulus. It is the numerator of the `1/7` remaining after integer division.

Answer (score 3):

Let's use different numbers for demonstration.

42 divided by 5 gives a quotient of 8 and a remainder of 2. That means `42 // 5 == 8` and `42 % 5 == 2`.

3 divided by 7 gives a quotient of 0 and a remainder of 3. That means `3 // 7 == 0` and `3 % 7 == 3`.

In Python, `//` and `%` represent the quotient and remainder you probably learned about before you learned about fractions and real numbers. The only (possible) difference is that `//` floors and `%` matches the sign of the right-hand operand.

Comment: You meant `3 // 7 == 0`. :P

Answer (score 0):

modulo returns the whole number after integer (floor) division.

```
>>>3//7
0 # with remainder 3
>>>3%7
3
>>>2//5
2 # with remainder 1
>>>2%5
1
```